# Flow - Property not found in statics of class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Given a class with a static property, and a method accessing that property via `this.constructor`:

```
class Matematica {
  reset() {
    this.constante = this.constructor.PI;
  }
}

Matematica.PI = 3.14
```

Flow is unable to find the static property `PI`:

```
xx: this.constructor.PI;
                     ^^ property `PI`. Property not found in
xx: this.constructor.PI;
    ^^^^ statics of Matematica

xx: Matematica.PI = {
               ^^ property `PI`. Property not found in
xx: Matematica.PI = {
    ^^^^^^^^^^ statics of Matematica
```

Why is Flow unhappy about this working code and what can I do to make it happy either in the code or in the flow configurations?

Comment: One solution would be to not make it at static at all and just have it be a variable in the file.

Comment: Can you add a type declaration like `static PI: number` to the class without an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
class Matematica {
  reset() {
    this.constante = this.constructor.PI;
  }

  static get PI() {
    return 3.14
  }
}
```